# How to make the caption in `lstlistings` to stick with the code inside?

Tags: algorithms, code, book-design, lstlisting

I have 3 pieces of code and I am using `lstlistings` to present it in my article.

The caption of the third listings is the previous page and the contents of the environment is in the new page.

How to correct this error?

I am not giving the MWE  since I dont know how to produce this situation.

I am giving the options which I am using in the environment.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={This Captions should stick with the below code and should not be in the previous page}\label{lst:somefunction}, mathescape]
def somefunction(A,beta, epsilon, d, NIter, realPrec):
     code ....
    return X
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Comment: You know how to reproduce the situation: You have a document that shows it. To get a MWE you only need to shorten it while keeping the problem. You can replace text with \vspace*{X\baselineskip}.

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy to prevent the page break automatically -- one would have to identify all possible break points first. But you can use the needspace package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{needspace}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{41\baselineskip}
abc

\Needspace*{4\baselineskip}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={This Captions should stick with the below code and should not be in the previous page}\label{lst:somefunction}, mathescape]
def somefunction(A,beta, epsilon, d, NIter, realPrec):
     code ....
    return X
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are using the package "listings", the `\lstlistings` command can take an optional argument `float` ( in addition to `caption`). E.g.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[float=tp,%
         caption={This Captions should stick with the below code and should not be in the previous page}\label{lst:somefunction},%
         mathescape]
    def somefunction(A,beta, epsilon, d, NIter, realPrec):
      /*code ....*/
    return X
\end{lstlisting}
```